# C# to VB.Net Conversion WINRT

Tags: c#, vb.net, winrt-xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I am trying to download sample from [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Date-and-time-formatting-2361f348/view/Discussions#content) for using date,time picker and when I'm trying to convert It gives me a lot of compilation issues as seen below using this [converter](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/Instant_VB.html) which I have used it till now and worked well when compared with developerusion and telerik converters to name a few.

As this converter just gives me 51 errors while others are increasing the count of errors by 10 :(

So can anyone provide me the sample for VB.Net or guide me to the one which can convert this sample to VB.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @downvoter-Care to comment instead of downvoting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the errors you are getting which start with "'Is' operator...", just change "Is" to "=" and "IsNot" to "<>".

The source of the bad conversion is that the converter is not a Windows Store App and does not load the .winmd files that are referenced.  We are still trying to sort this out (how do you make a product that will still run on the 37% of machines which still use Windows XP, yet also be able to load Windows Store App dlls).

Comment: @Dave-Thanks dave for your reply.Yes.. I agree to what you said and yes it's the "IS" operator...I have changed them and I got it managed to work..I really like your software which always provided me 100% accuracy than any other converter.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to read anything out of your screenshot, but [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) is good at converting between VB.NET and C#, you can try that one. Do mind, that it is definitely an advantage to be able to read C# when you code in VB.NET too. The syntax isn't that different, you should be able to understand it...

Answer (score 0):

Here's VB.NET version of same but it's older one i.e. for Windows 8

[Date and time formatting sample (Windows 8)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Date-and-time-formatting-3effef7d)

Comment: @Xyroid-Yes..I have seen for that but it don't have any controls...So it dosen't suit my requirement

Comment: Ok, so better you post the errors or your requirement rather than sharing screenshot [it's not visible at all].